# Replace substring of characters with awk and sed

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file which contains a very long string of characters and I would like to replace a substring of it with Ns. Example:

test

```
ABCDABCDABCD
```

I would like to replace a substring of it with all letters N with awk command and sed, all the characters from index 5 to 8, so the total length of letter N is 4.

Output

```
ABCDNNNNABCD
```

I tried something like this:

```
awk '{ v=substr($0,5,4); sed -i "s/$v/N/g";print substr($0,1,4)""v""substr($0,9,12)}' test
```

however, this command seems to give this output:

```
ABCDABCDABC
```

And no substitution was made

I would like to have in the code the number of the index from where to start the substitution, (here, for example, is 5) and the length number of the substitution ( here  4), so I can just modify these numbers in case I want to start in another position and for a different length of substitutions because in reality, I have a string with thousands of letter and I want to replace hundreds of characters so substitution of pattern does not work in my case

Comment: Awk is not like shell: you can't just put a sed call in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk, you can do

```
gawk -v start=5 -v end=8 '{
    mid = substr($0, start, end-start+1)
    print substr($0, 1, start-1) gensub(/./, "N", "g", mid) substr($0, end+1)
}' file
```

Or with perl

```
perl -spe 'substr($_, $start-1, $end-$start+1) =~ s/./N/g' -- -start=5 -end=8 file
```

With both solutions, we pass the start and end values to the program with command line options. This makes it easy to alter the values from within a shell script. If you need to make the replacement character N dynamic as well, it should be pretty obvious how.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU awk (gawk) you could set `FIELDWIDTHS` to split the line into fields based on character positions. This is particularly convenient for your case in gawk version >= 4.2, which supports a "wildcard" trailing fieldwidth. You can then replace characters in the second field using `gsub`:

```
echo ABCDABCDABCD | ./gawk -v i=5 -v n=4 '
  BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = sprintf("%d %d *", i-1, n)} 
  {gsub(/./,"N",$2)} 1
' OFS=""
ABCDNNNNABCD
```

In older versions of gawk, you can simulate the `*` by choosing a suitably large maximum size for the trailing field:

```
echo ABCDABCDABCD | gawk -v i=5 -v n=4 '
  BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = sprintf("%d %d 65536", i-1, n)} 
  {gsub(/./,"N",$2)} 1
' OFS=""
ABCDNNNNABCD
```

See

[Processing Fixed-Width Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fixed-width-data.html#Fixed-width-data)

[Capturing Optional Trailing Data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Allowing-trailing-data.html#Allowing-trailing-data)

Answer (score 2):

You can just try with below command

```
 echo "ABCDABCDABCD"| sed "s/ABCD/NNNN/2"
```

output

```
ABCDNNNNABCD
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Using sed

To replace characters 5 through 8 with `N`:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.{4}).{4}/\1NNNN/' test
ABCDNNNNABCD
```

How it works:

- `(.{4})` captures the first four characters in group 1.
- `.{4}` matches the next four characters.
- `\1NNNN` replaces the above with group 1 and four `N`.

#### Using GNU awk

```
$ gawk -F "" '{for (i=5; i<=8; i++) $i="N"} 1' OFS="" test
ABCDNNNNABCD
```

How it works:

- `-F ""` tells awk to treat each character as a separate field.
- `for (i=5; i<=8; i++) $i="N"` loops over each character from 5 through 8 and changes it to `N`.
- `1` tells awk to print the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by employing the following methods as shown with either POSIX or GNU seds

**With the sed editor:**

```
$ L=5 R=8
$ sed -e '
   s/./\n/'"$L"';s//\n/'"$R"';ta
   :a;s/\n\n/NN/;t
   s/\n./N\n/;ta
' ./test

ABCDNNNNABCD
```

**With Perl:**

```
perl -lspe '
   my $c = $idxr - (pos()=$idxl-1);
   s/\G.{$c}/"N"x$c/e;
' -- -idxl=5 -idxr=8 ./test

ABCDNNNNABCD
```